# Getting DataContractSerializer error

Tags: c#

I'm not sure to what i'm doing wrong here but its now been a couple of days of me trying to solve this out but still  no luck.

I have a model like this:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string EventName {get;set;}
    public DateTime StartTime{get;set;}
    public DateTime FinishTime {get;set;}
}
```

Then i have a web Api method like this :

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable GetTimes()
{
    var times = context.Events.where(x => x.EventName == "even name").Select(x => x new{

         x.Id,
         x.EventName,
         StartTime = x.StartTime.ToShortTimeString(), // just getting time only
         FinishTime = x.FinishTime.ToShortTimeString() // just getting time only
    });  
}
```

When I run my project I get the following error:

> ArrayOf_x003C__x003E_f__AnonymousType0Ofintstringstringstringstringdoubledoublestring:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are
>   using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer

I have never seen this error before and I'm not so sure on how to tackle this one.

I have also realized that when I run a test for instance if I do the following in that method:

```
x.Id,
x.EventName,
StartTime = "12.30", // this works fine and no error is thrown.
FinishTime = "16.30"

//also the following works fine:
x.Id,
x.EventName,
x.StartTime,
x.FinishTime, // this works fine obviously i only need the time only
```

How is this caused and how can I fix this?

Comment: You create an anonymous type. Instead of `new { ...}` do `new Event { ...}` in your projections

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/wcf-tutorial-serializing-and

Comment: I think your base class might need attributes such as knowntypeattribute

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your two last examples (without `ToShortTimeString()`) are working? This shouldn't be possible as the `DataContractSerializer` cannot serialize anonymous types.

Comment: yes i'm 100%  sure .. i just double checked and it worked .. i'm confused myself .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because the DataContractSerializer on the client side ,used for deserializing the result, is expecting an array of a specific type and the server is handing out an array of an anonymous type.  You need to use the same type on the server and client or 2 types that use the same Data Contract (which is how the generated proxy classes the VS creates work).

Try creating a Data Transfer Object (DTO) class to use on both client and server.

```
[DataContact]
public class EventDTO {

  [DataMember]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string EventName { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public TimeSpan EndTime {get;set;}
}
```

Nowe your get method can look like

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<EventDTO> GetTimes()
{
    return context.Events.where(x => x.EventName == "even name")
                       .Select(x => x new EventDTO
                                {
                                  Id = x.Id,
                                  EventName = x.EventName,
                                  StartTime = x.StartTime.TimeOfDay, 
                                  FinishTime = x.FinishTime.TimeOfDay
                                });  
}
```

Make sure you use the same type for your Deserializer on the client

Comment: But the OP wants only the *time* of `StartTime` and `FinishTime` -- not the whole date. So the new type (e.g. `EventDto`) has to have two `TimeSpan` properties.

Comment: Hi, |How do i go about setting the Timespan in my context above ? thank you

Comment: @Abbondanza I was reusing the OP's concrete type, which stored uses DateTime.  Answer now updated to include a DTO

Answer (score 0):

The DataContractJsonSerializer cannot serialize anonymous types. Are you allowed to use another built-in serializer? In that case you can use the standard JSON serializer by setting your `HttpConfiguration` as follows:

```
httpConfiguration.Formatters.Clear();
httpConfiguration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

You could also write a custom attribute to disable the `DataContractJsonSerializer` for a particular controller only:

```
public class UseDefaultJsonSerializerAttribute : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(
        HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings,
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        controllerSettings.Formatters.Clear();
        controllerSettings.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
}
```